# I have a array of arrays as in description need to convert it to formatted Hash in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a file with many arrays as below:

```
[["default", "'drop'"],
["rule", "49", "action", "'accept'"],
["rule", "49", "description", "'This one is for'"],
["rule", "49", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.4/20'"],
["rule", "50", "action", "'accept'"],
["rule", "50", "description", "'Once more'"],
["rule", "50", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.5/20'"]]
```

I want a ruby code which can make it look like following:

```
{
  'default': 'drop',
  'rule': { 
    '49': { 
      'destination': { 
        'address': '1.2.3.4/20' 
      },
      'action': 'accept', 
      'description': 'This one is for' 
    },
    '50': {
      'destination': {
        'address': '1.2.3.5/20'
      },
      'action': 'accept',
      'description': 'Once more'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried different approaches which is replacing and keeping only the last one or few keys are missing. Please help me in this.

Comment: does it need to be generic or just work for your exact case?

Comment: I want that to be generic as I have many such arrays which needs similar conversion required

Comment: Your expected result is invalid.

Comment: In your desired result I count 6 left parentheses and 5 left parentheses (@sawa's point). I don't think your `json` tag should be there.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I actually missed that point. What I had in mind is the space between the `'...'` and the colon in the hash sugar notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another recursive solution. One advantage of using recursion is that the array can be of arbitrary size.

```
arr = [
  ["default", "'drop'"],
  ["rule", "49", "action", "'accept'"],
  ["rule", "49", "description", "'This one is for'"],
  ["rule", "49", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.4/20'"],
  ["rule", "50", "action", "'accept'"],
  ["rule", "50", "description", "'Once more'"], 
  ["rule", "50", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.5/20'"]
]

def recurse(arr)
  arr.group_by(&:first).transform_values do |a|
    a.map! { |r| r.drop(1) }
    a.size == 1 && a[0].size == 1 ? a[0][0] : recurse(a)
  end
end

recurse arr
  #=> { "default"=>"'drop'",
  #     "rule"=>{
  #       "49"=>{
  #         "action"=>"'accept'",
  #         "description"=>"'This one is for'",
  #         "destination"=>{"address"=>"'1.2.3.4/20'"}
  #       },
  #       "50"=>{
  #         "action"=>"'accept'",
  #         "description"=>"'Once more'",
  #         "destination"=>{"address"=>"'1.2.3.5/20'"}
  #       }
  #     }
  #   }
```

Note that the first step is as follows.

```
arr.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"default"=>[["default", "'drop'"]],
  #    "rule"=>[["rule", "49", "action", "'accept'"],
  #             ["rule", "49", "description", "'This one is for'"],
  #             ["rule", "49", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.4/20'"],
  #             ["rule", "50", "action", "'accept'"],
  #             ["rule", "50", "description", "'Once more'"],
  #             ["rule", "50", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.5/20'"]]}
```

Comment: When I tried this I'm getting following error: undefined method `transform_values' for #<Hash:0x007fd3fb837558> (NoMethodError). Can you correct me what is that I'm missing.

Comment: I think thats because the version of Ruby I'm using is 2.2.2. The support for this came later in 2.3 or later

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) made it's debut in v2.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

This makes use of passing a block to [`Hash::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) which keeps passing that same block to new sub hashes, via the [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc):

```
output = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }
```

Now, we can just iterate the array, and we know the last value in each subarray becomes the final value (ie, not sub hashes off of it) and everything else needs to create a new sub-hash, which is done above, when we access a key without a value, so we can access all intermediate keys by use of [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig), we also need to convert all the keys into symbols, and (it appears) remove single quotes from the beginning and end of the values:

```
array.each_with_object(output) do |(*nesting, key, value), hash|
  hash = nesting.empty? ? hash : hash.dig(*nesting.map(&:to_sym))

  hash[key.to_sym] = value.gsub(/(\A\'|\'\z)/, '')
end
```

Running that with `array` set to your input array we get the following out:

```
{
  :default => "drop",
  :rule => {
    :"49" => {
      :action => "accept",
      :description => "This one is for",
      :destination => {
        :address => "1.2.3.4/20"
      }
    },
    :"50" => {
      :action => "accept",
      :description => "Once more",
      :destination => {
        :address => "1.2.3.5/20"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Novel! Clever! However, if `g` is the hash returned, `g['cat'] #=> {}`, `g['cat'] #=> {}`, `g['rule']['cat'] #=> {}`, `g['rule']['49']['cat'] #=> {}` and `g['rule']['49']['destination']['cat'] #=> {}`. That is, the default procs are still there. This could cause some debugging headaches. They could be effectively be removed (e.g., `g.default_proc = Proc.new { nil }`), but a few more steps would be required.

Comment: Good point @Cary, I often forget about that because in my code, the setting of a default proc never really matters if it sticks around (ie, afterwords all I usually end up doing is iterating or I can check for a key with `has_key?` in the rare case I don't want to trigger the proc)...if you want to blow out this default proc, I think you end up needing to recurse anyway, to make sure it clear it out on all the sub hashes it ended up creating, so it won't save you having to do recursion...but if you're fine with that proc sticking around this is short and sweet and nice

Comment: As a general observation, I suppose if one wanted to effectively remove "nested" default procs one could do something like this: 1) define all the default procs in terms of the method  `def default(h,k) h[k] = {} end`; that is, `h.default_proc = Proc.new { |h,k|  default(h,k) }`. Later, when the default procs are no longer wanted, simply redefine `default`: `def default(h,k) nil end`. (`default` could of course be a proc instead of a method.) Yes?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hash
  def deep_store(keys, value)
    if keys.size > 1
      self[keys.first] ||= {}
      self[keys.first].deep_store keys[1..-1], value
    else
      self[keys.first] = value
    end
    self
  end
end

input = [
  ["default", "'drop'"],
  ["rule", "49", "action", "'accept'"],
  ["rule", "49", "description", "'This one is for'"],
  ["rule", "49", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.4/20'"],
  ["rule", "50", "action", "'accept'"],
  ["rule", "50", "description", "'Once more'"],
  ["rule", "50", "destination", "address", "'1.2.3.5/20'"]
]

result = input.each_with_object({}) do |(*keys, value), hash|
  hash.deep_store keys, value
end

puts result

# => {"default"=>"'drop'", "rule"=>{"49"=>{"action"=>"'accept'", "description"=>"'This one is for'", "destination"=>{"address"=>"'1.2.3.4/20'"}}, "50"=>{"action"=>"'accept'", "description"=>"'Once more'", "destination"=>{"address"=>"'1.2.3.5/20'"}}}}
```